# sources.list entry for mod_security testing release?

Tags: debian, mod-security, debian-squeeze

I have a debian "squeeze" installation, but the mod_security delivered with this release is quite old. So I'm thinking of adding an additional line to my sources.list to get the "wheezy" version (wheezy = the version after the current version "squeeze") of mod_security.

What should I add to sources.list to receive only the next available version of mod_security?

This is one of my entires in sources.list:

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free
```

The current name of mod_sec is `libapache-mod-security`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Careful - adding a full new repository can light up new versions for more than just that one individual package, putting you in [this situation](https://serverfault.com/questions/302938/i-accidentally-upgraded-a-server-to-a-debian-testing-distribution-now-what).

Feel free to add the repo:

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
```

**BUT**, don't let it get used for more than just the package you need from it, unless you want to update the whole system.

Modify your `/etc/apt/preferences` file, adding configuration to lower the priority of the `testing` release:

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=testing
Pin-Priority: 450
```

And up the priority for the package that you're interested in (by the way, the package name changed):

```
Package: libapache2-modsecurity
Pin: release a=testing
Pin-Priority: 550
```

Verify with `apt-cache policy` that the testing repo is lower than the stable repos, and verify with `apt-cache policy libapache2-modsecurity` that the individual package prefers testing.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the explanation! When I run `apt-cache policy` the wheezy branch does not show up. Do I have to refresh apt-get, or something else?

Comment: @powtac Yeah - `apt-get update`

Comment: found it already. Now wheezy shows up with 450 when running `apt-cache policy` and libapache2-modsecurity not. I think this is ok?

Comment: And I can now run apt-get upgrade without problems?

Comment: When I start apt-get, bastille shows up without updated, when I revert all changes from above back, bastille does not show up?!

Comment: Check where it's trying to come from - `apt-cache policy bastille`?

Comment: `apt-cache policy bastille` outputs: `450 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main i386 Packages` and `100 /var/lib/dpkg/status`